# Python socket file ValueError

Tags: python, file, sockets, valueerror

I am trying to use sockets to connect to a server and I can't get pass this error message:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

sf = s.makefile("rw")

for i in file.readlines():

    password = i.strip('\n')

    credentials='root'+","+password

    sf.write("{}\n".format(credentials))
```

I get a

> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

for the last line.

Any help on why this is?

Comment: I don't think `rw` is a valid mode for `s.makefile()`.

Comment: Maybe I need to add that everything worked fine, until I added the for loop and had the sf.write in an other block. The problem must be somehow related to that.

Comment: Maybe the server is closing the connection after it reads the first line.

Comment: Is it really expecting multiple lines of `root,password` inputs?

Comment: After each iteration I am closing the sf(file abstraction for the socket) because I want to try different credentials for the same connection. The server is not closing the connection but maybe I need to move the s.makefile() in the for loop.

Comment: Did you opened file in your code ? before using `for i in file.readlines():`

Comment: I don't see that in the code you posted.

Comment: @SandeepLade If he didn't open the file, how could he get to the `sf.write()` line?

Comment: If you want to keep trying on the same connection, don't close anything.

Comment: @Barmar if I don't close the file I get a EOF error.

Comment: That's a different error than the one in the question?

Comment: Why do you think you can try different credentials for the same connection? Is the server really expecting multiple credentials?